# Problem with rearrange dataframe using melt/cast

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I've like to use cast function (reshape package) for returns to original dataframe state, but doesn't work.
In my example:

```
#First simulate some data
set.seed(123)
bands=5
data <- data.frame(matrix(runif(10*bands),ncol=bands))
colnames(data) <- paste0(1:bands)
data$nitrogen <- rpois(10,10)
data$Class<-rep("test",10)
#

# Reshape with melt function 
library(reshape)
data2 <- melt(data, id=c("nitrogen","Class"))

#Return to original data state again
data3<-cast(data2, Class+nitrogen~variable)
data3
  Class nitrogen 1 2 3 4 5
1  test        4 1 1 1 1 1
2  test        5 1 1 1 1 1
3  test        6 2 2 2 2 2
4  test        8 1 1 1 1 1
5  test       11 1 1 1 1 1
6  test       12 4 4 4 4 4
```

I expected:

```
           1          2         3          4         5 nitrogen Class
1  0.2875775 0.95683335 0.8895393 0.96302423 0.1428000        4  test
2  0.7883051 0.45333416 0.6928034 0.90229905 0.4145463        6  test
3  0.4089769 0.67757064 0.6405068 0.69070528 0.4137243        6  test
...
10 0.4566147 0.95450365 0.1471136 0.23162579 0.8578277       11  test
```

Doesn't work my cast approach for return to data object, any member help me please?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combinations of Class and nitrogen are not unique: there are four times where Class == "test" and nitrogen == 11, two times where Class == "test" and nitrogen == 6. From the help documentation:

> If the combination of variables you supply does not uniquely identify one row in the original data set, you will need to supply an aggregating function, fun.aggregate. This function should take a vector of numbers and return a summary statistic(s).

So, `cast` will aggregate the repeated combinations. You won't be able to get back to the original data unless you put in some sort of dummy variable that makes the combinations unique.

```
data$dummy <- 1:10

data3 <- cast(data2, Class + nitrogen + dummy ~ variable)
data3
   Class nitrogen dummy         1          2         3          4         5
1   test        4     1 0.2875775 0.95683335 0.8895393 0.96302423 0.1428000
2   test        5     5 0.9404673 0.10292468 0.6557058 0.02461368 0.1524447
3   test        6     2 0.7883051 0.45333416 0.6928034 0.90229905 0.4145463
4   test        6     3 0.4089769 0.67757064 0.6405068 0.69070528 0.4137243
5   test        8     4 0.8830174 0.57263340 0.9942698 0.79546742 0.3688455
6   test       11    10 0.4566147 0.95450365 0.1471136 0.23162579 0.8578277
7   test       12     6 0.0455565 0.89982497 0.7085305 0.47779597 0.1388061
8   test       12     7 0.5281055 0.24608773 0.5440660 0.75845954 0.2330341
9   test       12     8 0.8924190 0.04205953 0.5941420 0.21640794 0.4659625
10  test       12     9 0.5514350 0.32792072 0.2891597 0.31818101 0.2659726
```

Change the order of columns and drop the dummy if you want it to be exactly the same.

```
data3[,c(4:8, 2, 1)]
           1          2         3          4         5 nitrogen Class
1  0.2875775 0.95683335 0.8895393 0.96302423 0.1428000        4  test
2  0.9404673 0.10292468 0.6557058 0.02461368 0.1524447        5  test
3  0.7883051 0.45333416 0.6928034 0.90229905 0.4145463        6  test
4  0.4089769 0.67757064 0.6405068 0.69070528 0.4137243        6  test
5  0.8830174 0.57263340 0.9942698 0.79546742 0.3688455        8  test
6  0.4566147 0.95450365 0.1471136 0.23162579 0.8578277       11  test
7  0.0455565 0.89982497 0.7085305 0.47779597 0.1388061       12  test
8  0.5281055 0.24608773 0.5440660 0.75845954 0.2330341       12  test
9  0.8924190 0.04205953 0.5941420 0.21640794 0.4659625       12  test
10 0.5514350 0.32792072 0.2891597 0.31818101 0.2659726       12  test
```